# Qsort and issues with it

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

The following is my code and Qsort produces strange result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char values[] = { 0x02,0x04,0x0b,0x16,0x24,0x30,0x48,0x6c};

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main ()
{

    int i;

    qsort (values, 8, sizeof(char), compare);

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
       printf ("%0x ",values[ i ]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is program is:

## 2 6c 48 30 24 4 b 16

Though it should have been the same as the input. Can someone please explain the reason why it is so and how I can correct it?

Comment: I cannot believe this. A **fully self-contained, compilable example**! You, sir, deserve a *medal* for this! +1, and more if I could.

Comment: Good point, @DevSolar, we _should_ reward questions like this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
```

You should *not* be comparing `int` values if the underlying "objects" are `char` values.

What's almost certainly happening is that the comparison is using the four (depending on `sizeof(int)`) bytes to do the comparison, such as the first object being `0x02040b16` (depending on your endian-ness of course). This will greatly stuff up the process.

Change it to:

```
return ( *(char*)a - *(char*)b );
```

and try again.

And just be aware that the signed-ness of `char` is an implementation issue. You may find that `0x80` ends up being less than `0x7f`. If that's not what you want, use `unsigned char` explicitly to *extract* the values, then upgrade them to signed integers (with another cast) before doing the subtraction.

In fact, for portability, you may want to use `signed char` explicitly for the other case as well.

The following program shows how it works with the correct underlying data type:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

signed char values[] = {0x02, 0x04, 0x0b, 0x16, 0x24, 0x30, 0x6c, 0x48};

int compare (const void *a, const void *b) {
    return *(signed char*)a - *(signed char*)b;
}

int main (void) {
    int i;

    qsort (values, 8, sizeof (char), compare); // char okay here.
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
       printf ("%0x ", values[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

The ouput of this is:

```
2 4 b 16 24 30 48 6c
```

(I swapped the order of the final two elements in the code so as to show it was actually sorting something).

Comment: "This will greatly stuff up the process." -- Yup ... the values being sorted actually change during the sort!

Comment: If OP was sorting unsigned chars, would `return *(unsigned char *)a - *(unsigned char *) b` be wrong because the subtraction could never produce a negative result?

Comment: Good point @Adrian, modified text to state they should be upgraded to `signed int` before the subtraction. Although, even there, you may run into trouble with weird architectures that have same size for char and int (unlikely).

Comment: @paxdiablo compare returns an int, so return `*(unsigned char *)a - *(unsigned char *)` can produce negative results as it is calculated as int.

Answer (score 4):

Change your compare function to

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( *(char*)a - *(char*)b );
}
```